# Schedule running code every 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, cron, cron-task

Hi I'm using a twando script on my server for scheduling the list of tweets.
I have a problem with cron process, and I need to run cron url every 60 seconds. How can I make a `php` code to load the cron url every min?

Answer (score 0):

I think we cannont do it through PHP code, use HTML or javascript to reload the page..
we can do it in HTML like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="60">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use short polling method java script and ajax

java script

```
 var doStuff = function () {
      // Do ajax request php script
          $.post( "ajax/cron.php", function( data ) {
            $( ".result" ).html( data );
});

    };
    setInterval(doStuff, time);
```

or if your server Linux set up  corn tab